# Colors in emacs terminal version looks weird

Tags: emacs, terminal, spacemacs

I opened issue on the spacemacs github page, but maybe I can find a workaround here?

When I open spacemacs in terminal colors looks weird, what can I do with that?
While emacs loading colors looks fine, but then background and other colors changes.

[While loading looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E1SL.png)

[When loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgDmG.png)

Terminal: iTerm2

OS: darwin

Emacs: 26.1

Spacemacs: 0.200.13

Spacemacs branch: master (rev. c7a103a)

Graphic display: nil

Distribution: spacemacs

Editing style: vim

Completion: ivy

Layers:

(ivy python auto-completion better-defaults emacs-lisp git)

System configuration features: JPEG RSVG IMAGEMAGICK NOTIFY ACL GNUTLS LIBXML2 ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS NS MODULES THREADS LCMS2

My config: https://gist.github.com/karambaq/d757ee1bd3c631a03d5ec468fdcfd660

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, not a link to some other place where you asked it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. done

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the themes change a bit.

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes

That's the huge package that sets the themes in spacemacs...

Try

```
M-x: powerline-theme
```